# regexp_matches - ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Tags: regex, postgresql

So I'm getting an error message when running regexp_matches on postgres and cannot figure out how to get passed it. It appears to work fine on reg_exp test sites like regex101 but unfortunately does not work when applied practically. The error message is:

**ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid**

```
select email, regexp_matches(email,'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}+[0-9]{6}') as pattern
from table
limit 10
```

It's a relatively simple pattern of 4 alphabet characters and 6 numbers within an email prefix. Perhaps '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}+[0-9]{6}' might not be the best way? Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: `{4}+` makes no sense, `{4}` means "exactly four times" while `+` means "one time or more", you can't apply both to the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` character class. If you wanted a literal `+` character, escape it (`\+`). If you want the character class to happen four times or more, use `{4,}`. If you want the character class to happen a non-zero multiple of four times, use `([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})+`

Comment: If I get your description right, you should just remove the `+`.

Comment: `{4}+` is a *possessive*  quantifier, but PostgreSQL regex does not support it. Anyway, `{4}+` = `{4}`.

Comment: Great thank you all. Yes removing the + is giving me results I can now work with. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}+[0-9]{6}` pattern is not compatible with the PostgreSQL regexp engine because it does not support [**possessive quantifiers**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). `{4}+` is a possessive [**limiting quantifier**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) here that match 4 occurrences of the quantified pattern without any possibility to backtrack into these 4 chars. Since the `max` argument is not used (i.e. not something like `{4,7}`), the `{4}+` possessive quantifier works the same way as `{4}`.

Use `{4}` instead of `{4}+`:

```
select email, regexp_matches(email,'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{6}') as pattern
from table
limit 10
```

Besides, if the pattern is to match the *entire* record, add `$` (end of string) anchor at the end of the pattern:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{6}$'
```